# Transform pairs of rows into single row

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table that looks like this

```
|=========|=====|==================|==============|===========|===========|
| PREFIX  | ID  | PREVIOUS_PREFIX  | PREVIOUS_ID  | VENDOR_1  | VENDOR_2  |
|=========|=====|==================|==============|===========|===========|
| A       | 1   |                  |              | JAC       |      BOA  |
|---------|-----|------------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
| B       | 2   | C                | 99           | LCH       |      GS   |
|---------|-----|------------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
| B       | 3   | C                | 99           | LCH       |      JPM  |
|---------|-----|------------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
```

I need to turn it into a table that looks like this

```
|=========|=====|==================|==============|===========|===========|
| PREFIX  | ID  | PREVIOUS_PREFIX  | PREVIOUS_ID  | VENDOR_1  | VENDOR_2  |
|=========|=====|==================|==============|===========|===========|
| A       | 1   |                  |              | JAC       |      BOA  |
|---------|-----|------------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
| C       | 99  |                  |              | GS        |      JPM  |
|---------|-----|------------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
```

That is:

1. For rows with no `PREVIOUS_PREFIX` and `PREVIOUS_ID` it leaves that row as is
2. For rows with `PREVIOUS_PREFIX` and `PREVIOUS_ID`:

   1. it creates a new row whose `PREFIX` is the same as `PREVIOUS_PREFIX`, `ID` is the same as `PREVIOUS_ID` and `VENDOR_1` and `VENDOR_2` are the vendors not common to the original pair of rows
   2. It deletes the original pair of rows

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Create sample data */
data have;
    input Prefix $ ID Previous_Prefix $ Previous_ID Vendor_1 $ Vendor_2 $;
    cards;
A 1  .  .  JAC BOA
B 2  C  99 LCH GS
B 3  C  99 LCH JPM
E 5  F  52 LOK U
E 5  F  52 LOK M
    ;;;
run;

/* Assign new values for Prefix & ID */
data want;
    set have;
    if Previous_Prefix ne '' then do;
        Prefix = Previous_Prefix;
        Previous_Prefix = '';
    end;
    if Previous_ID ne . then do;
        ID = Previous_ID;
        Previous_ID = .;
    end;
run;

/* Merge Vendor_1 & Vender2 into one column */
data want2;
    set want;
    if first.ID then n = 0;
    n + 1;
    by ID notsorted;
run;

proc transpose data=want2 out=want3(drop=n _NAME_ rename=(COL1=Vendor));
    by Prefix ID n Previous_Prefix Previous_ID;
    var Vendor_1 Vendor_2;
run;

/* Delete common Vendor_ */
proc sort data=want3;by Prefix ID Previous_Prefix Previous_ID Vendor;run;

proc summary data=want3;
    output out=want4(where=(_freq_ = 1));
    by Prefix ID Previous_Prefix Previous_ID Vendor notsorted;
run;

/* Transpose data from long back to wide */
proc transpose data=want4 out=want5(drop=_:) prefix=Vendor_;
    var Vendor;
    by Prefix ID Previous_Prefix Previous_ID notsorted;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

a slightly simpler solution would be be expand single observation into 2 observation and getting vendors into single variable and along with that coalescing previous_prefix and prefix to get new_prefix and similarly for id. get data in this order can solve your problem in single sql. check out this draft code.

```
DATA WANT;
SET HAVE;
  PREFIX_NEW =COALESCEC(PREVIOUS_PREFIX,PREFIX);
  ID_NEW     =COALESCEC(PREVIOUS_ID    ,ID);
IF NOT MISSING(VENDOR_1) THEN VENDOR=VENDOR_1; 
OUTPUT;
IF NOT MISSING(VENDOR_2) THEN VENDOR=VENDOR_2; 
OUTPUT;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
SELECT PREFIX_NEW
     , ID_NEW
     , MIN(VENDOR) AS VENDOR_1
     , MAX(VENDOR) AS VENDOR_2
FROM ( SELECT PREFIX_NEW
            , ID_NEW
            , VENDOR
            , COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
         FROM WANT
         GROUP BY 1,2,3
         HAVING COUNTER=1
      )
;
QUIT;
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a single data step, if your data is as simple as you've said.  My assumptions are that there are only a maximum of 2 rows with duplicate Prefixes and there are always only 2 unique Vendor id's.  The data also needs to be sorted by Prefix and ID, if not done so already.

The main requirements are fairly straightforward to achieve using a combination of `first.` and `last.` to determine if there are duplicate Prefix rows and to set the required values.  The trickier part is the Vendor logic, I've done this by creating a temporary variable to hold a list of all names, checking first to see if the current name already exists.  If it does then it removes this name from the list, otherwise it gets added.

I've added plenty of comments to the code to explain what is happening, hopefully it is fairly clear.  As there are only a maximum of 2 iterations per Prefix (I hope), I've duplicated a couple of lines of code rather than creating a `do loop`.

```
/* create dummy data */
data have;
input Prefix $ ID Previous_Prefix $ Previous_ID Vendor_1 $ Vendor_2 $;
datalines;
A 1  .  .  JAC BOA
B 2  C  99 LCH GS
B 3  C  99 LCH JPM
;
run;

/* transform data */
data want;
set have;
by prefix id;
length _vendors $30; /* temporary variable to hold Vendor names */
retain _vendors; /* keep values from previous row where necessary */
if first.prefix and last.prefix then output; /* if only one Prefix row then output */
else do;
    if first.prefix then call missing(_vendors); /* clear vendor list when Prefix changes */
    if index(_vendors, compress(vendor_1)) then _vendors = tranwrd(_vendors,compress(vendor_1),''); /* if Vendor name already exists in list then remove it */
        else call catx(',',_vendors,vendor_1); /* else add Vendor name to comma separated list */
    if index(_vendors, compress(vendor_2)) then _vendors = tranwrd(_vendors,compress(vendor_2),''); /* repeat previous step for Vendor_2 */
        else call catx(',',_vendors,vendor_2);
    if last.prefix then do; /* for last Prefix record, set the required values and output record */
    prefix = previous_prefix; 
    id = previous_id;
    call missing(previous_prefix,previous_id);
    vendor_1 = scan(_vendors,1);
    vendor_2 = scan(_vendors,2);
    output;
    end;
  end;
drop _vendors; /* drop temporary variable */
run;
```